# Arch wifi keeps dropping

Tags: arch-linux, dns, wifi

I recently installed Arch, wifi has been messing around. Dropping and generally not connecting. I fixed it by ruling it was DHCP not getting a lease in time, I assigned a static IP and all is good. But for some reason every now and again I can't visit certain sites and domains(.net,.com) etc... If I use netctl to stop the profile then set my interface to down then restart prfile it works for a while again. I have no idea where to look for this. My /etc/resolv.conf has 4 nameservers (googles, and open dns) so they're good. Any idea where to look next?

Comment: Are you sure that isn't that your AP is too far of the receptor? Have you tried another OS's?

Comment: Nah mate, i can visit certain domains but for example I will be able to visit .coms but not .nets, i restart profile then bam back to normal